# Incorporating OR-Tools in a CMake Project

Tags: or-tools, c++

I'm trying to incorporate or-tools into my cmake project.

I've tried some of the suggestions given by the project maintainers, who give a few different ways to integrate or-tools [in the readme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649334/difference-between-static-and-shared-libraries) and in a [template project](https://github.com/or-tools/cmake_or-tools). I've tried both, yielding the same result.

The first method is building locally and using cmake's `find_package`:

```
################
##  OR_TOOLS  ##
################
message(STATUS "Installing OR-Tools...")
# Download and install or-tools at configure time
configure_file(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/ortools.CMakeLists.txt
${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ortools-download/CMakeLists.txt)
# CMake configure
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ortools-download)
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for ortools failed: ${result}")
endif()
# CMake Build/Install
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
  RESULT_VARIABLE result
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ortools-download)
if(result)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for ortools failed: ${result}")
endif()
message(STATUS "Installing OR-Tools...DONE")

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps)
find_package(ortools REQUIRED)
```

where in the `cmake` directory I have a file `ortools.CmakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(ortools-download NONE)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(ortools_project
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/or-tools.git
  GIT_TAG "stable"
  GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
  GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
  CMAKE_ARGS
    "-G@CMAKE_GENERATOR@"
    "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"
"-DBUILD_DEPS=ON"
"-DBUILD_SAMPLES=OFF"
"-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF"
"-DBUILD_TESTING=OFF"
"-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps"
)
```

and the second is to use cmake's `FetchContent`.

```
    include(FetchContent)
    FetchContent_Declare(
            ortools
            GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/or-tools.git
            GIT_TAG        stable
    )

    set(BUILD_DEPS ON)
    set(BUILD_SAMPLES OFF)
    set(BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF)
    FetchContent_MakeAvailable(ortools)
    set(requiredlibs ${requiredlibs} ortools::ortools)
```

Both give the same error, at runtime:

`ERROR: Something is wrong with flag 'flagfile' in file 'Users/username/project-root/cmake-build-debug/ortools-download/ortools_project-prefix/src/ortools_project-build/_deps/absl-src/absl/flags/parse.cc'. One possibility: file 'Users/username/project-root/cmake-build-debug/ortools-download/ortools_project-prefix/src/ortools_project-build/_deps/absl-src/absl/flags/parse.cc' is being linked both statically and dynamically into this executable. e.g. some files listed as srcs to a test and also listed as srcs of some shared lib deps of the same test.`

For reference, I'm on an Apple Silicon Mac, using cmake 3.22.3, compiling with the flag:
`-DCMAKE_APPLE_SILICON_PROCESSOR=arm64`. I've tried both `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` and `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`.

EDIT:

I partially figured it out, however I still have a question: I want to compile a dynamic library from many shared libraries in my project. The static libraries need to be linked to `ortools` because they reference that library. However, I then want to build a shared library that merges all the separate static libraries together, this doesn't work. Why is that the case, and is there a way to fix it?

Below is my current solution so if anyone else has this issue they can reference. I ended up using the `FetchContent` method, with a few modifications.

The error gives a hint as to what was happening: "is being linked both statically and dynamically into this executable".

In c++ there are two types of libraries: [static and dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649334/difference-between-static-and-shared-libraries). My code builds many static libraries and links them to a dynamic library, which is then linked to the executable file.

project structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt # creates the dynamic library
│   ├── [various .cc/.h files]
│   ├── staticlib1
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt # creates a static library
│   │   └── [various .cc/.h files]
│   └── staticlib2
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt # creates another static library
│       └── [various .cc/.h files]
└── main.cc
```

The key is that `ortools::ortools` can only be linked to either multiple static libraries, or multiple dynamic libraries. It cannot be linked to both static and dynamic libraries.

In `src/CMakelists.txt` I create a dynamic library and was linking to ortools:

```
project(project)

SET(SOURCE_FILES_SRC
        example.cc
)

add_subdirectory(staticlib1)
set(requiredlibs ${requiredlibs} staticlib1)

add_subdirectory(staticlib2)
set(requiredlibs ${requiredlibs} staticlib2)

add_library(${DISPATCHER_LIB} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES_SRC})
target_link_libraries(${DISPATCHER_LIB} ${requiredlibs} ortools::ortools) # linking to dynamic(shared) ortools lib
```

However, I was also linking to `ortools::ortools` in the static libraries in `src/staticlib1/CMakeLists.txt` which caused the issue:

```
project(project)

set(staticlib1_SOURCE_FILES
        example2.cc)

add_library(staticlib1 STATIC ${staticlib1_SOURCE_FILES})
set_property(TARGET staticlib1 PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
target_link_libraries(staticlib1 ${requiredlibs} ortools::ortools) # linking to static ortools
```

To fix this, changed the dynamic library to a static library

```
project(project)

SET(SOURCE_FILES_SRC
        example.cc
)

add_subdirectory(staticlib1)
set(requiredlibs ${requiredlibs} staticlib1)

add_subdirectory(staticlib2)
set(requiredlibs ${requiredlibs} staticlib2)

add_library(${DISPATCHER_LIB} ${SOURCE_FILES_SRC}) # now a static library
target_link_libraries(${DISPATCHER_LIB} ${requiredlibs})
```

I also had to change the `FetchContent` block in `CMakeLists.txt` to disable building the ortools dynamic libraries.

```
set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET OFF)
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        ortools
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/or-tools.git
        GIT_TAG        stable
)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF) # disables dynamic(shared) library building
set(BUILD_DEPS ON)
set(BUILD_SAMPLES OFF)
set(BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(ortools)
```

As I stated above, at the beginning of the edit, I would like this line

`add_library(${DISPATCHER_LIB} ${SOURCE_FILES_SRC}) # now a static library`

in `src/CMakeLists.txt` to be a dynamic library:

`add_library(${DISPATCHER_LIB} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES_SRC}) # now a static library`

is there a way to make that work given that I need ortools to link to the static libraries that it is composed of?

Comment: Try changing `project(ortools-download NONE)` to specify the language: `project(ortools-download LANGUAGES C CXX)`.

Comment: With that change, the `FetchContent` version worked fine for me on an M1. Otherwise was getting some compiler error when compiling CBC (it's a dep). Also, add `set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET OFF)` to see what's going on.